# How to user babel emotion macro in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, babeljs, emotion

I'm trying to use `emotion` in my `create-react-app`, but getting errors when using the macro method [explained here](https://emotion.sh/docs/babel-plugin-emotion#babel-macros).

I just tried copying over the import code in a component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "react-emotion/macro";
import { css, keyframes, injectGlobal, flush, hydrate } from "emotion/macro";
import css from "@emotion/css/macro";
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";

function Registration(props) {
  return;
}

export default Registration;
```

The first error I get is `Parsing error: Identifier 'css' has already been declared`. So I commented out the `import css` and `import styled` lines to see if it would return anything else. This gave me the error `Cannot find module 'react-emotion/macro' from ...`.

What step am I missing? Or is there another way that I should be including `emotion` in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone has the same problem. With v10 of `emotion` and `create-react-app` (I believe greater than v2), `react-emotion` is not required. Also, I didn't need `styled`, so with the following it works:

```
import React from "react";
import css from "@emotion/css/macro";

function Registration(props) {
  return
}

export default Registration;
```